# Install Button Not Showing in Google + Account

Tags: android, android-layout

I am integrating Google +1 api  in my android application for +1 Recommendation & sharing.When i share my application using android phone install button not show in google+ account .Where user can be directly download.But when i share using web browser it show install button.

Kindly suggest me how it is possible to show direct install button when user share my application.

Answer (score 0):

With the Google+ platform for Android, you are now able to integrate a native +1 button in your Android app.

1) You first need to [intialize +1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/#initialize_the_plusclient) the PlusClient object in your Activity.

2) Include the PlusOneButton in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
    xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
    android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    plus:size="standard"
    plus:annotation="inline" />
```

3) Assign the PlusOneButton to a member variable in your Activity.onCreate handler.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mPlusClient = new PlusClient(this, this, this, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE);
     mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
    }
```

4) Refresh the PlusOneButton's state each time the activity receives focus in your Activity.onResume handler.

```
 protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
  // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
   mPlusOneButton.initialize(mPlusClient, URL);
  }
```

For more information, see

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/#recommend_content_with_the_1_button

Once you get the clickEvent on Google+ button set it's visibility--->GONE and set your Install button visibility-->VISIBLE

Hope it may helps!!